# $.fancybox.open('#home-pop'); style div onload fancybox

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

Does anyone know how to style a fancybox div when trying to open it onload.

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $.fancybox.open('#home-pop');


});
```

I Need something like this... But i cant figure out how to style the fancybox div when I use the code above.

```
     $("#home-pop").fancybox(
     {
      fitToView : true,
      width     : '100%',
      height        : '100%',
      autoSize  : false,
      closeClick    : true,
      openEffect    : 'none',
      closeEffect   : 'none',
     padding : '0',
      margin : '0'
       });
```

Comment: Could you use this syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8766344/2287470 but replace `#contentdiv` with `#home-pop`?

Comment: no i read that already. it is not opening the div onload. thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

this worked !

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fancybox({
          fitToView : true,
      width     : '100%',
      height        : '100%',
      autoSize  : false,
      closeClick    : true,
      openEffect    : 'none',
      closeEffect   : 'none',
      padding : '0',
      margin : '0',
            'href': '#home-pop'
        });
       });
```