# how to check fancybox open or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, get, fancybox

I just want to check a textbox to open Fancybox.
If the textbox is empty then I want Fancybox to work else I just want to redirect another page. how can I do this.

The below code I have my Fancybox whenever I click 'Inline' then the div open.

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1">Inline</a>  
<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <h3>Etiam quis mi eu elit</h3> 
</div>
```

but I have another button with its textbox and it search something in my web page.

```
<form action="/Isim/Arama" method="get">    
    <input type="text" id="searchedPart" class="searchedName generalTextArea" name="searchedPart" value=""> 
    <input class="searchNameSearchButton" type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

now I want the following

if searchedPart is empty
 then show fancybox
else
  do what it does currently

Comment: Where is your code that opens Fancybox

Comment: <a class="fancybox" href="#inline1">Inline</a>  @putvande

Comment: i did by controlling fancy box with function 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094233/open-fancybox-from-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript can help you to solve this "if searchedPart is empty,then show fancybox
else do what it does currently"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#searchedPart').keyup(function() {
       if($('#searchedPart').val()) {
         $('.fancybox').css('display','none');
       }
   });
});
```

Good Luck!