# On click function fires only on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I find few answers on this theme, but none of them helped me.

My on click fires on second click - where is the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   $("#back-in-stock-subscribe").click(function () {
      var sku = document.getElementById('back-in-stock-sku-to-get').textContent;
      var action = '@Url.RouteUrl("BackInStockSubscribePopup", new { productSku = "sku" })';
      action = action.replace("sku", sku);

      $("#back-in-stock-subscribe").fancybox({
           'href': action,
           'transitionIn': 'none',
           'width': 500,
           'height': 200,
           'type': 'iframe',
           'centerOnScroll': true
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `Fancybox` inited after you first click on your element. What do you expect?

Comment: apply a console.log or  alert on the click handler and check it triggers on first click or not

Comment: @u_mulder thank you, i didn't realized that earlier. I don't know how to mark you answer.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code on click initializes the fancy box but you need to call the click event on the fancybox itself to launch it.

Try adding .click() at the end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   $("#back-in-stock-subscribe").click(function () {
      var sku = document.getElementById('back-in-stock-sku-to-get').textContent;
      var action = '@Url.RouteUrl("BackInStockSubscribePopup", new { productSku = "sku" })';
      action = action.replace("sku", sku);

      $("#back-in-stock-subscribe").fancybox({
           'href': action,
           'transitionIn': 'none',
           'width': 500,
           'height': 200,
           'type': 'iframe',
           'centerOnScroll': true
      }).click();
   });
});
</script>
```

Looking at this :

[Open fancybox from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094233/open-fancybox-from-function)

Comment: will it not result in an infinite loop if `.click()` again calls `.click(function`?